# Developing TypeScript without an installed IDE or editor

Tags: javascript, typescript, ide

I work in a place that restricts me from downloading and installing any applications, regardless of job roles. I have several web apps that I want to migrate to Angular 2 with TypeScript. I'm a C# developer in my own time and TypeScript is very appealing as it's statically typed and just compiles down to JavaScript.

How can I develop with TypeScript without having access to an installed IDE or code editor? Are there any online environments that allow the use of TypeScript definition files that provide code help/intellisense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Codenvy](https://codenvy.com/):
It needs some manual tweaks but somebody figured them out already: https://groups.google.com/a/codenvy.com/forum/#!topic/codenvy/R4myXA9MygA

Answer (score 3):

> How can I develop with TypeScript without having access to an installed IDE or code editor

I am hoping you can do `npm install typescript`. If you can just run `npm install typescript -g` and then run typescript as `tsc -w -p tsconfig.json` in your code directory. This will allow you to run the compiler in the background leaving you free to use even notepad if you have to.

Alternatively you can just download the zip file from : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/releases and if you have node you can run `node ./bin/tsc` etc from the extracted directory.

Comment: Sadly command prompt is even restricted here. I work as a developer in a call center, and all the group policies for the usual phone rep are also applied to myself and coworkers. The same goes for running any non-whitelisted applications. Thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the playground: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground
Although it doesn't allow references to other files.